# Linear Mixed Model? How to conduct in relation to my thesis

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, nested-data

I am having some confusion over how to carry out the stats for my experiment.

In the experiment, there is two condition of teaching method "prof-generated" and "student-generated" and the DV is students' quiz scores over 4 quizzes. 
As I carried out the experiment in a real classroom setting under my prof's module, I could not do a fully crossed design and had a lot of restrictions.
Instead, all students first go through the "prof-generated" condition in the first half of the semester and took quiz 1 and 2 in the same period.
Following that, they then go through the "student-generated condition" in the 2nd half of the semester and took quiz 3 and 4 in the same period.

I am trying to find out the effectiveness of student-generated condition over prof-generated but realised time could be a factor that could affect students' improvement in quiz scores as a natural course of the module.

At first, I did a 2-way repeated measures anova and got significant results in treatment factor and insignificant results in time and interaction.
However, my stats tutor told me that my time factor is nested within treatment and I cannot do that. I tried doing linear mixed model in SPSS but got very very confused as I have never learnt that before (even after hours of youtube videos).

I tried putting DV as quiz scores, treatment as fixed variable, time as fixed variable and random variable and subjects as random variable but had no idea how to analyze and interprete the results to show that time is not affecting the quiz results and only treatment does (specifically student-generated > prof-generated).

Thanks in advance:)

Regards